# unexpected T_ELSE error in my code, can someone see it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I can't find my error, can I have some help? I'm trying a login code with a cookie. Thank you in advance! I just cant seem to see my error. I was hoping someone can see something that I am missing. The error is somewhere at the 47th Line, but I know that doesn't exactly mean that that is where it is.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sent']) && $_POST['sent'] == "yes")
    {
        foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
        {
            if($value == "")
            {
                $blank_array[$field]= $value;
            }
            else
            {
                $good_data[$field]=strip_tags(trim($value));
            }
        }
    }

    if(@sizeof($blank_array) > 0)
    {
        $message = "<p style='color: red; margin-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold'> Error.</p>";
        extract($blank_array);
        extract($good_data);
        include("form_log.php");
        exit();
    }

    include("dbstuff.php");
    $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("coulnt connect");
    $query = "SELECT first_name FROM customer WHERE user_name='$_POST[user_name]' AND       password=md5('$_POST[password]')";
    $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die ("couldnt query");
    $n_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($n_row < 1)
    {
        $message = "<p style='color: red; margin-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold'> Not found.     </p>";
        extract($_POST);
        include("form_log.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        setcookie("first_name",$row['first_name']);
        setcookie("auth","yes");
        header("Location: secret_page_cookie.php");
    }

    else
    {
        $user_name = "";
        $password = "";
        include("form_log.php");
    }
?>
```

Sorry for no indentation but this is hard to indent. The second else goes to if(@sizeof)..

Comment: There's a reason why nearly all developers format their code using indentation.

Comment: I am obligated to mention SQL injection attacks and weak password hashing here.

Comment: also, using `include` like you do is something you're going to regret pretty soon, it's totally impossible to actually read what's going on in this code without also opening that form_log.php file.  Looks like an ideal candidate for converting into a function to me!

Answer (score 7):

```
if ($n_row < 1) {
    $message = "<p style='color: red; margin-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold'> Not found.     </p>";
    extract($_POST);
    include("form_log.php");
    exit();
} else {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    setcookie("first_name",$row['first_name']);
    setcookie("auth","yes");
    header("Location: secret_page_cookie.php");
} else {
    $user_name = "";
    $password = "";
    include("form_log.php");
}
```

You have two `else` statements here. You'll need to figure out which `if` statement it belongs to or convert it to an `elseif` condition.

Answer (score 4):

Line 47:

```
else
{
$user_name = "";
$password = "";
include("form_log.php");
}
```

There can only be one `else` for every `if` this is the second `else`.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two else blocks towards the end, there should only be one. And your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Don't construct SQL strings by concatenation, use parameterised queries instead.

Comment: `parameterised` Word of the day.

Comment: At east it might be now I've corrected the earlier typo ... iPad being too clever... ;)